# bounds to the nearest 5.

Tags: upper-lower-bounds

"Ebony makes bracelets. the materials cost £190, correct to the nearest £5. Ebony sells all the bracelets for a total of £875, correct to the nearest  £5. the total time taken to make and sell was 72 hours, correct to the nearest hour. Ebony uses this method to calculate her hourly rate of pay:
hourly rate of pay = (total selling price - total cost of materials)/total time taken

the minimum hourly rate of pay for someone of Ebony's age is £8.20. By considering bounds, determine if Ebony's hourly rate of pay was definitely more than £8.20.

Comment: Not a site for homework...